# list view selection issue in android

Tags: android, android-listview, listselectionlistener

I have a listview defined in xml

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_results"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ListView>
```

Drawable -> list_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_pressed="true"><color android:color="@color/blue"/></item>
<item  android:state_hovered="true"><color android:color="@color/blue"/></item>
<item><color android:color="@color/blue"/></item>

</selector>
```

Now, I have a dialog box which pops up on selecting an item from the list view. The row which was clicked is highlighted.

Requirement:- On selection of 'No' from the dialog, the listview row item should get deselected. I want it to get transparent.

I have the NegativeDialogClickEvent and I have tried 
lv.setSelection, lv.setBackgroundColor but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Instead of using listselector use custom listrow. And update background color on checkbox check/uncheck status.

Comment: Try to notify your adapter class as you get the click event of your negative button and rebind your listview again.

Comment: lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  lv.invalidateViews();   I was able to achieve with this. but somehow on scroll the blue color still persists. Is it a right solution?

Comment: @GrIsHu: not working

Comment: @RaghuRamiReddy: I don't have anything else in the listview accept for displaying the text. Still I should go with the custom option. Is there not any other way of achieving it?

Comment: Please show your code of dialog and listview. @androiddeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Keep the checked position in global variable on list item checked.
Let's say checked position is 2. Keep this position in `mClickedPos = 2;`

And get the callback of "No" option select on dialog. Add the below code.

```
listView.setItemChecked(mClickedPos, false);
```

Please refer the below link to know more about listView setItemChecked() method.

[link-for-reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29)